# Qt - Use builtin translations

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qtranslator

I'm using Qt and want to translate the texts "natively" shown by Qt widgets. By "texts natively shown" I'm for instance referring to the ones shown in context menus for text edits (copy, paste, ...).

Here is what I've already done:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTranslator>

#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    if(translator.load("qt_fr.qm", QApplication::applicationDirPath())) {
        qDebug() << a.installTranslator(&translator);
    }

    qDebug() << QFile::exists(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qt_fr.qm"); // just to debug file existence

    // MainWindow w;      // not related to my question
    // w.showMaximized(); // neither is this

    return a.exec();
}
```

The **qt_fr.qm** file is located at **path_to_qt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/mingw49_32/translations** for Qt5.6.2 and MinGW users. I copy the said file to the running software directory but the translator always fails to load it. But when I use my own qm file (built from a .ts file using the Qt lupdate and lrelease tools), the qm file is properly loaded and installed.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Qt will append a suffix (default `.qm`) first, so I'd recommend removing that from the filename argument.  Note that the documentation recommends using the overload that accepts a `QLocale` as first argument, too.  For example, `translator.load(QLocale::French, "qt", QApplication::applicationDirPath())`.

Comment: Indeed you're right: the loading process is straightforward if no extension is added to the filename. But since Qt backtracks and retries when load fails, adding the .qm extension shouldn't have lead to failure.

I also tried the version with QLocale but it still does not work. Any other suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Furthermore, using QLocale assumes that the qm file we're loading matches with the language installed on the OS running our software. But [sometimes](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8e48efe46e756e80f900584241c5c108ebc7fcef/68747470733a2f2f757365722e6f632d7374617469632e636f6d2f75706c6f61642f323031372f30312f32362f31343835343536393833393335385f696d6734372e706e67) we may choose english while being German (for instance).

The above-provided snippet of mine works fine when I use my own .qm file (lupdate & lrelease) but when it comes to loading Qt builtin .qm files, the loading process fails.

Comment: My comment was just a "best practice" rather than a solution (which was why it's a comment and not an answer).  But it definitely allows use of a locale that's not supported by the OS - hence my use of `QLocale::French` (and, implicitly, the constructor that accepts a `QLocale::Language`) rather than simply `QLocale{}`.  As to solving the problem, I'd be interested to read some actual answers, and learn a bit more for myself about translation in Qt.

Comment: You're definitely right. It's even stated in the doc: shame on me. Anyway hope somebody will be able to provide me with a solution since it seems that the Qt builtin .qm files are not deployed the same way as those I would create myself (using lupdate & lrelease). And yet I'm not using various versions of Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you haven't copied the complete message catalog.  The following works for me on a Debian system, using the QM files in their standard locations:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    const QString dir = "/usr/share/qt5/translations";

    if (translator.load("qt_fr", dir)) {
        qDebug() << "first load succeeded:"
                 << "'Open' =>" << translator.translate("QShortcut", "Open");
    }

    if (translator.load(QLocale::French, "qt", "_", dir)) {
        qDebug() << "second load succeeded:"
                 << "'Open' =>" << translator.translate("QShortcut", "Open");
    }
}
```

Output is

```
first load succeeded: 'Open' => "Ouvrir"
second load succeeded: 'Open' => "Ouvrir"
```

(I removed the `.qm` from the filename, as Qt will try that first, and I've also shown how to compose the filename from a specific locale object).

If we inspect the `qt_fr.qm` file using `lconvert -of ts /usr/share/qt5/translations/qt_fr.qm`, we can see it's just a very small file that incorporates other files by reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="fr_FR">
<dependencies>
<dependency catalog="qtbase_fr"/>
<dependency catalog="qtscript_fr"/>
<dependency catalog="qtquick1_fr"/>
<dependency catalog="qtmultimedia_fr"/>
<dependency catalog="qtxmlpatterns_fr"/>
</dependencies>
</TS>
```

I think that the most likely cause of your symptoms is that one or more of the dependency files could not be loaded.  You should ensure that all of those files area available in the same location that you copied `qt_fr.qm` to - or, if you only need the "base" translations, just copy `qtbase_fr.qm`, and change your `translator.load()` call appropriately.

Comment: Indeed I didn't copy the dependency files and that's why the translator always failed at loading the qm file. I now also realize that since I only want to translate text edit contextual menus, loading **qtbase_fr** perfectly suits my needs and no dependency file is required. Thanks a lot, I would have 10 up-voted if I could. :) Btw how do you know about the lconvert tool? That is I've never heard of it, I'm not that new to Qt and unless somebody told me, I know no magic tricks that could have helped me out. _Sorry for the tenses, not a native english speaker here_.

Comment: LConvert seems not to be very well known - it's only mentioned briefly in passing in the Qt documentation, and doesn't come with a manual page.  Everything I know about it I learnt using `lconvert -help`.  And yes, I should have suggested you might need only the `qtbase` translations, but you seem to have worked that out without my help!  :-)  I've edited the last paragraph a little, for future readers.